# How to add web link url in text view in Android?

Tags: android, textview, linkify

I am getting few google drive attachment links. I want to show them in the text view. But they should be appeared like Attachment 1, Attachment 2 - this way.

Attachment 1 will have a web link and attachment 2 will have another. They should be clickable.

I tried this way but it is not working:

```
    mStrAttach = new ArrayList<>();

 if(attchment_arr != null)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < attchment_arr.length(); i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    mStrAttach.add(attchment_arr.getString(i));
                }
                catch (JSONException e)
                {

                }

            }
        }
      if(mStrAttach.size() > 0)
            {
                view.attchment.setText("");
                for(int k = 0; k< mStrAttach.size(); k++)
                {
                    String devid = mStrAttach.get(k);
                    Log.d("Testing", "drive id:::  "+devid);
                    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Attachment "+""+(k+1));
                    ss.setSpan(new URLSpan(devid),0,ss.length(),0);
                    view.attchment.append(ss + "\n");
                }
                Linkify.addLinks(view.attchment, Linkify.ALL);
            }
```

But it is not coming as a link. I am not able to click the Attachment 1 or 2.
Can someone please help.

Thanks,
Arindam.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your attachement link in `TextView` Tag,

```
textview1.setTag(first_link);
textview2.setTag(second_link);
```

then whenever you want it just use `textview1.getTag()`, `textview2.getTag()`;

Comment: I have a single Textview. The text view is under an adapter. I can't create multiple.

Comment: single textview can have multiple attachment??....its better to use multiple textview using recyclerview view or programatically generate textviews as you want.

Comment: single textview can have multiple attachment. yes, it is possible. I am able to add the multiple attachment link. But I want to hide them.

Comment: if(mStrAttach.size() > 0)
        {
            view.attchment.setText("");
            for(int k = 0; k< mStrAttach.size(); k++)
            {
                String devid = mStrAttach.get(k);
                Log.d("Testing", "drive id:::  "+devid);
                view.attchment.append(devid + "\n");
            }
            Linkify.addLinks(view.attchment, Linkify.ALL);
  }. This works when I am not hiding it.